# Explicit calculation of residue field in Cyclotomic integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to show that $(1-\zeta)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, where $\zeta=\zeta_p =e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$, for a prime $p$.

I am aware that we can show $(1-\zeta)=(1-\zeta^i)$, for $1\leq i\leq p-1$, and then show that $$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}(1-\zeta^i)=1+1+\ldots+1$$ $p$ times, meaning that $(1-\zeta)^{p-1}=(p)$, and hence $(1-p)$ is prime, since $p-1$ is the maximum power we can allow when factoring ideals in this Galois extension.

However, I want to show it's prime by considering $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]/(1-\zeta)$.

I can make an educated guess that distinct coset representatives could be $1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{p-1}$, which would give us $p$ elements in the residue field, meaning that the ideal has a prime norm, showing that if it factored the factors must be of norm $1$ or $p$.

I suppose I just can't see a way to specifically show that these are representatives, or even whether I need to take multiplicative or addititve cosets.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or just correct me if I've confused myself in my reasoning I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphism $\mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta) \cong \mathbb Z[t]/(t^{p-1} + \ldots + 1,1-t) \cong \mathbb Z/p$ is given by $\zeta \mapsto t \mapsto 1$.

Since $\zeta^i \equiv 1 \in \mathbb Z[\zeta]/(1-\zeta)$, your elements do not form a set of representatives. Rather, one is given by $\zeta,\ \zeta + 1,\ \ldots,\ \zeta + (p-1)$, as seen by following the isomorphism above.

To answer your question about cosets, recall that the quotient of a ring by an ideal is defined as additive groups first, and then given the unique ring structure which respects the projection.

Comment: How does the first isomorphism come about? ($\zeta\mapsto t$)

Comment: The universal property of the polynomial ring.